# Using WHERE clause on NATURAL JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, natural-join

I am studying the book Database System Concepts 6th ed. which uses the example of a university database. 
The schema of this database is as follows. The bold represent the primary keys:

```
department(dept_name, building, budget)
course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits)
instructor(ID, name, dept_name, salary)
section(course_id, sec_id, semester, year, building, room number, time_slot_id)
teaches(ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year)
prereq(course_id, prereq_id)
```

In the book the following query is stated:

"List the names of instructors along with the the titles of courses that they teach".

The answer given by the book is:

```sql
select name, title
from instructor natural join teaches, course
where teaches.course id = course.course id;
```

Furthermore, the writer goes:

"In contrast the following SQL query does not compute the same result:

```sql
select name, title
from instructor natural join teaches natural join course;
```

To see why, note that the natural join of instructor and teaches contains the attributes
(ID, name, dept name, salary, course id, sec id), while the course relation contains the
attributes (course id, title, dept name, credits). As a result, the natural join of these
two would require that the dept name attribute values from the two inputs be the
same, in addition to requiring that the course id values be the same. This query
would then omit all (instructor name, course title) pairs where the instructor
teaches a course in a department other than the instructor’s own department.
The previous query, on the other hand, correctly outputs such pairs. "

Now I tried both queries to see myself the difference.

```
mysql> select * from instructor;
+-------+------------+------------+----------+
| ID    | name       | dept_name  | salary   |
+-------+------------+------------+----------+
| 10101 | Srinivasan | Comp. Sci. | 65000.00 |
| 12121 | Wu         | Finance    | 90000.00 |
| 15151 | Mozart     | Music      | 40000.00 |
| 22222 | Einstein   | Physics    | 95000.00 |
| 32343 | El Said    | History    | 60000.00 |
| 33456 | Gold       | Physics    | 87000.00 |
| 45565 | Katz       | Comp. Sci. | 75000.00 |
| 58583 | Califieri  | History    | 62000.00 |
| 76543 | Singh      | Finance    | 80000.00 |
| 76766 | Crick      | Biology    | 72000.00 |
| 83821 | Brandt     | Comp. Sci. | 92000.00 |
| 98345 | Kim        | Elec. Eng. | 80000.00 |
+-------+------------+------------+----------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from course;
+-----------+----------------------------+------------+---------+
| course_id | title                      | dept_name  | credits |
+-----------+----------------------------+------------+---------+
| BIO-101   | Intro. to Biology          | Biology    |       4 |
| BIO-301   | Genetics                   | Biology    |       4 |
| BIO-399   | Computational Biology      | Biology    |       3 |
| CS-101    | Intro. to Computer Science | Comp. Sci. |       4 |
| CS-190    | Game Design                | Comp. Sci. |       4 |
| CS-315    | Robotica                   | Comp. Sci. |       3 |
| CS-319    | Image Processing           | Comp. Sci. |       3 |
| CS-347    | Database System Concepts   | Comp. Sci. |       3 |
| EE-181    | Intro. to Digital Systems  | Elec. Eng. |       3 |
| FIN-201   | Investment Banking         | Finance    |       3 |
| HIS-351   | World History              | History    |       3 |
| MU-199    | Music Video Production     | Music      |       3 |
| PHY-101   | Physical Principles        | Physics    |       4 |
+-----------+----------------------------+------------+---------+

mysql> select * from teaches;
+-------+-----------+--------+----------+------+
| ID    | course_id | sec_id | semester | year |
+-------+-----------+--------+----------+------+
| 76766 | BIO-101   | 1      | Summer   | 2009 |
| 76766 | BIO-301   | 1      | Summer   | 2010 |
| 10101 | CS-101    | 1      | Fall     | 2009 |
| 45565 | CS-101    | 1      | Spring   | 2010 |
| 83821 | CS-190    | 1      | Spring   | 2009 |
| 83821 | CS-190    | 2      | Spring   | 2009 |
| 10101 | CS-315    | 1      | Spring   | 2010 |
| 45565 | CS-319    | 1      | Spring   | 2010 |
| 83821 | CS-319    | 2      | Spring   | 2010 |
| 10101 | CS-347    | 1      | Fall     | 2009 |
| 98345 | EE-181    | 1      | Spring   | 2009 |
| 12121 | FIN-201   | 1      | Spring   | 2010 |
| 32343 | HIS-351   | 1      | Spring   | 2010 |
| 15151 | MU-199    | 1      | Spring   | 2010 |
| 22222 | PHY-101   | 1      | Fall     | 2009 |
+-------+-----------+--------+----------+------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select name, title
-> from instructor natural join teaches, course
-> where teaches.course_id = course.course_id;
+------------+----------------------------+
| name       | title                      |
+------------+----------------------------+
| Crick      | Intro. to Biology          |
| Crick      | Genetics                   |
| Srinivasan | Intro. to Computer Science |
| Katz       | Intro. to Computer Science |
| Brandt     | Game Design                |
| Brandt     | Game Design                |
| Srinivasan | Robotica                   |
| Katz       | Image Processing           |
| Brandt     | Image Processing           |
| Srinivasan | Database System Concepts   |
| Kim        | Intro. to Digital Systems  |
| Wu         | Investment Banking         |
| El Said    | World History              |
| Mozart     | Music Video Production     |
| Einstein   | Physical Principles        |
+------------+----------------------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select name, title
    -> from instructor natural join teaches natural join course;
+------------+----------------------------+
| name       | title                      |
+------------+----------------------------+
| Crick      | Intro. to Biology          |
| Crick      | Genetics                   |
| Srinivasan | Intro. to Computer Science |
| Katz       | Intro. to Computer Science |
| Brandt     | Game Design                |
| Brandt     | Game Design                |
| Srinivasan | Robotica                   |
| Katz       | Image Processing           |
| Brandt     | Image Processing           |
| Srinivasan | Database System Concepts   |
| Kim        | Intro. to Digital Systems  |
| Wu         | Investment Banking         |
| El Said    | World History              |
| Mozart     | Music Video Production     |
| Einstein   | Physical Principles        |
+------------+----------------------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

From the result I see no difference and moreover I don't understand why should there be a difference.
Unlike what the book the states, the natural join of *instructor* and *teaches* contains the attributes *ID, name, dept name, salary, course id, sec id, semester, year*.

Comment: You never showed sample data for the `course` table, but books sometimes have typos.

Comment: Yes you are right. I just edited it.

Comment: @ginos book is right.

Comment: I don't see why the natural join would be any different from the first explicit join.  From what I can see, only the join columns have the same name.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I respect your answer. Where is my mistake since I don't see any difference in the results.

Comment: There is a difference but maybe not in your data. Both instructor and course has **dept_name** and they could be different. So the queries are not equivalent.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There is **dept_name**

Comment: Don't use `natural join`!  I consider it an abomination because it does not even use properly declared foreign key relationships for the join keys.  Instead, use proper, explicit, **standard** `join` syntax, with `on` or `using` clauses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book is correct. These queries are not equivalent. Sample data(*detp_name* values are different):

```
INSERT INTO course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits)
VALUES (1, 'Course_1', 'DeptX', 10);
INSERT INTO instructor(ID, name, dept_name, salary)
VALUES (1, 'Prof X', 'DeptY', 10000);
INSERT INTO teaches(ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year)
VALUES (1, 1, 10,10,2000);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7e5abceb2e0b902cddca0a4285a616b)**

Personally I wouldn't use any of proposed queries:

```
-- mixing natural join with old-comma syntax
select name, title
from instructor natural join teaches, course
where teaches.course_id = course.course_id;
--Output
--name      title
--Prof X    Course_1

-- natural join(potentially dangerous-depends on names of columns)
select name, title
from instructor natural join teaches natural join course;
-- 0 rows selected
```

And rewrite it as:

```
SELECT i.name, c.title
FROM instructor i
JOIN teaches t
  ON t.ID = i.ID
JOIN course c
  ON t.course_id = c.course_id;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ab9a1b3044838b2d3f774b2f1d8ff08)**

Comment: Thank you @Lukasz Szozda